# Первая авторизация в  phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Cкачал phpmyadmin? а там нужна авторизация. Пожалуйста, подскажите откуда брать логин и пароль?

Comment: Логин и пароль требуются для доступа к серверу базы данных. Прописывать там нужно рутовый пароль (указывается при установке сервера, обычно это root/mysql, в крайнем случае можно довольно просто сбросить), в крайнем случае те логин/пароль, которые использует сайт для подключения к своей БД.

Comment: А нельзя ли скачать phpmyadmin без вот этого чтобы сразу открывалось

Comment: @ААА, phpmyadmin к настройкам БД вообще никакого отношения не имеет. Другое дело, что в конфиге наверняка прописываются логин-пароль, которые более не запрашиваются.

Comment: Сможете дать ссылку на phpmyadmin со всеми конфигурациями,что бы не запрашивал логин и пароль

Comment: @ААА, еще раз: логин и пароль зависят от той установки MySQL, к которой этот phpmyadmin должен подключаться. Я с этим вообще ничего не могу сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вводить нужно логин и пароль от MySQL.